# Envers AuditReader reader fail

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-envers

I have an error when i use enver reader, the audit on db works fine, but when i need create reader i get error..

this is the line:

```
reader.isEntityClassAudited(App_UserDto.class);
```

Where App_UserDto have @Audited tag.

cause this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.isProxyClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    org.hibernate.envers.internal.tools.EntityTools.getTargetClassIfProxied(EntityTools.java:78)
    org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.isEntityClassAudited(AuditReaderImpl.java:298)
    cl.sw.appCenter.sys.audit.AuditLectura.getUserAuditado(AuditLectura.java:31)
    cl.sw.struts.sys.action.UsuariosAction.usuariosLista(UsuariosAction.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    ............
```

App_UserDto:

```
@Entity
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="user.getUserByUser",
                query="FROM App_UserDto WHERE user = :user"),
}) 
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
public class App_UserDto implements DTO{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="gen_USERS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="gen_USERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_APP")
    @Column(name="ID",nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NOMBRE")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name="APELLIDO")
    private String apellido;

    @Column(name="USUARIO")
    private String user;

    @Column(name="CLAVE")
    private String clave;

    @Column(name="ACTIVO", insertable=false)
    private String activo;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="FONO")
    private String fono;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_PERFIL",nullable=true)
    private App_PerfilDto perfil;
    .....
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

any sugestion?

my DTO.. here.

```
public interface DTO extends Serializable{

    public String getRegistro();
    public void cleanRegistro();

}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your DTO interface by chance?

Comment: Hi, thanks for ask.... yes of course

Comment: What version of javassist is on your classpath?  Looks like it could be a mismatch is why you're getting this problem.

Comment: Hi, I have two javassist version on maven library 3.1.8.1 and 3.1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**: In my Maven library there were two versions of javassist.jar , one of Hibernate and other in struts2-core , removed the Struts 2 and it worked.